# After publishing my Google Apps app to the Chrome Webstore, it installs as an extension

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I've uploaded the following manifest for my Chrome Web Store submission

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Pear Deck",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "description": "for Active Classrooms",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/google-icon-128x128.png",
    "16": "icons/google-icon-32x32.png"
  },
  "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE", "GOOGLE_DRIVE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "1234567890"
}
```

I've zipped up the icons, filled out the form, and published to trusted testers (just approved).

But... when my trusted tester account goes to the Chrome Web Store and clicks install, the app is added as an extension to Chrome, not installed as a domain app.  I haven't specified a website or anything in this manifest (maybe that's why it thinks I have made an extension?), but I thought it would look up my console project id to install it in the drive UI.

What else do I need to do to get this installing as a normal Google Apps Marketplace app?  Do I need to also make it a "packaged app?"

Comment: Can you share your Chrome Web Store item id? It can be found in the developer dashboard.

Comment: It's `ihneapgpphojaoakeocoegjfgedegnmk` .  I will be happy to add trusted testers if you have time to check out the behavior from the customer POV.  Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the app it looks like that your Google Apps Marketplace api isn't configured (at all?) I'll take this to email if you don't mind me looking up your registered address.

Comment: Yes, I'd love an email at riley@peardeck.com, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eventual answer for this was to ignore the docs and specify both an app section and a DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE and GOOGLE_DRIVE container. Here's our manifest, which is working great - it can be installed from the "Add Marketplace Apps" button in admin.google.com, and also installed from the Chrome Web Store.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Pear Deck Beta Preview",
    "version": "0.0.0.10",
    "description": "for Active Classrooms",
    "icons": {
        "128": "YOUR_ICON_128x128.png",
        "16": "YOUR_ICON_16x16.png"
    },
    "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE", "GOOGLE_DRIVE"],
    "api_console_project_id": "YOUR_ID",
    "app" : {
        "launch" : {
            "web_url" : "https://peardeck.com/home"
        }
    }
}
```