# After I published my app to chrome webstore, it installs it as an extension.

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

My issue is very similar to this one:
[After publishing my Google Apps app to the Chrome Webstore, it installs as an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665021/after-publishing-my-google-apps-app-to-the-chrome-webstore-it-installs-as-an-ex)

Essentially, I filled out all the information as requested by the documentation on google and despite that, my app is still being installed as an extension rather than a marketplace domain app.

There are no solutions available and so I would like any advice or help if possible. I will post a solution here if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a lot of people are having this issue, a solution was posted here: [After publishing my Google Apps app to the Chrome Webstore, it installs as an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665021/after-publishing-my-google-apps-app-to-the-chrome-webstore-it-installs-as-an-ex)

but that wasn't working for me, I'd give it a shot as it may work for you though.